# fabric8: how does helm goal work?

Tags: fabric8

We're using `fabric8` maven plugin in order to build and deploy our maven projects into kubernetes.

I don't quite figure out how to use `fabric8:helm` goal.

I've tried to get some details about what exactly it makes, but I don't quite get it:

```
$ mvn help:describe -Dgoal=helm -DgroupId=io.fabric8 -DartifactId=fabric8-maven-plugin -Ddetail
```

And this is the output:

```
fabric8:helm
  Description: Generates a Helm chart for the kubernetes resources
  Implementation: io.fabric8.maven.plugin.mojo.build.HelmMojo
  Language: java
  Bound to phase: pre-integration-test

  Available parameters:

    helm
      (no description available)

    kubernetesManifest (Default:
    ${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/kubernetes.yml)
      User property: fabric8.kubernetesManifest
      The generated kubernetes YAML file

    kubernetesTemplate (Default:
    ${basedir}/target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/k8s-template.yml)
      User property: fabric8.kubernetesTemplate
      The generated kubernetes YAML file

    skip (Default: false)
      User property: fabric8.skip
      (no description available)

    ...
```

Inside our projects we have out artifacts inside `src/main/fabric8`. The content of this folder is:

```
tree src/main/fabric8
src/main/fabric8
├── forum-configmap.yaml
├── forum-deployment.yaml
├── forum-route.yaml
└── forum-service.yaml
```

These are files only related with kubernetes.

I've not been able to find any snippet over there about:

1. Which kind of files do I need to add on my project? helm files?
2. Which is exactly the output of this goal?

Comment: Hi, Did you look at plugin documentation regarding this? http://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:helm

Answer (score 1):

Just to play around with this I grabbed a basic spring boot project with Web dependency and a RestController created with the [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/). The [fabric8 plugin docs](http://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:helm) say to run the resource goal first so I went to the base directory of my project and ran `mvn -B io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.41:resource`. That generated kubernetes descriptors for my project under `/target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/`.

So then I ran `mvn -B io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.41:resource io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.41:helm`. At first I got an error that:

`target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/k8s-template does not exist so cannot make chart <project_name>. Probably you need run 'mvn fabric8:resource' before.`

But the descriptors did exist under `/target/classes/META-INF/fabric8/kubernetes/` so I just renamed that directory to `k8s-template` and ran again. Then it created a helm chart for me in the `/target/fabric8/helm/kubernetes/` directory.

So I followed the [the docs literally](http://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:helm) and then ran `helm install target/fabric8/helm/kubernetes/`. That complained there was no Chart.yaml. I realised then that I had followed the doc too literally and needed to run `helm install target/fabric8/helm/kubernetes/<project_name>`. That did indeed create a helm release and install my project to kubernetes. It didn't start as I hadn't created any docker image. It seems to default to an image name of `<groupId>/<artifactId>:<version/snapshot-number>`. Presumably that would've been there if I'd also run the ['build' goal](http://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:build) and [push](http://maven.fabric8.io/#fabric8:push) goals and had a docker registry accessible to my kubernetes.

So in short the helm goal generates a basic helm chart. I believe you'd need to customise this chart manually if you have an app that needs to access shared resources with urls or credentials being injected (e.g. for a database or message broker or authentication system) or if your app exposes multiple ports or if you need initContainers or custom startup parameters. Presumably you are trying to customize these generated resources and are doing so by putting files in your /src/fabric8/. If it's the k8s files that you're trying to feed through then I guess they'd have to go in `/src/fabric8/kubernetes/` in order to feed through into the expected `/target/` directory and also be named `<project-name>-deployment.yml` and `<project-name>-svc.yml`.

I guess the generated chart is at least a starting-point and presumably the experience can be a bit smoother than my experimenting was if you add all the plugin to the pom and do all the setup rather than running individual goals.